# Painting over satin wall that has sand texture

Tags: painting, paint

I need to paint a wall that's got a bit of sand in the finish, which looks like satin paint.

I've read that it's good to sand satin before repainting. But flat sandpaper can't get past the top of the grit. How do I prepare the surface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a paint with primer infused and a 1/2 inch nap roller.
Keep the roller wet, don't try to stretch the paint too far.

If the wall is clean free of dust and oils you can paint over satin just fine.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it would be easier to put 1/4" drywall up over the wall(s), prime and paint.  They sell vacuum sanders, but I think that project would be brutal.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I really hope this isn't necessary.